# Eclipse doesn't recognize new plugins under /plugins folder

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

We developed a new plugin in Eclipse using the Plugin-Development Tool.
Then, we exported it into `.jar` file that we copy to `Applications/STS/Eclipse/plugins`.

For some Mac users, this works and when restarting Eclipse they do <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>, and then are able to see the plugin in the wizard that's opened.
And for some, they see nothing.
What could be the reason for that?

Comment: Putting things directly in the plugins folder has not been supported for a long time. You could try starting with the `-clean` option. But the proper way to do things is use 'Export deployable plugins and fragmets' and do a proper install.

Comment: hey, so i used export deployable plugins and fragments and created a jar file. Whats the best way to install it if not through the plugins folder?

Comment: You have to copy it into the `dropins` folder instead of into the `plugins` folder: https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/p2_dropins_format.html